# Creating fuzzy matching exceptions with Python's new regex module

Tags: python, regex, pypi-regex

I'm testing the new python [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module, which allows for fuzzy string matching, and have been impressed with its capabilities so far. However, I've been having trouble making certain exceptions with fuzzy matching. The following is a case in point. I want `ST LOUIS`, and all variations of `ST LOUIS` within an edit distance of 1 to match `ref`. However, I want to make one exception to this rule: the edit cannot consist of an insertion to the left of the leftmost character containing the letters `N`, `S`, `E`, or `W`. With the following example, I want inputs 1 - 3 to match ref, and input 4 to fail. However, using the following `ref` causes it to match to all four inputs. Does anyone who is familiar with the new regex module know of a possible workaround?

```
input1 = 'ST LOUIS'
input2 = 'AST LOUIS'
input3 = 'ST LOUS'
input4 = 'NST LOUIS'


ref = '([^NSEW]|(?<=^))(ST LOUIS){e<=1}'

match = regex.fullmatch(ref,input1)
match
<_regex.Match object at 0x1006c6030>
match = regex.fullmatch(ref,input2)
match
<_regex.Match object at 0x1006c6120>
match = regex.fullmatch(ref,input3)
match
<_regex.Match object at 0x1006c6030>
match = regex.fullmatch(ref,input4)
match
<_regex.Match object at 0x1006c6120>
```

Comment: have you tried `(?<=[^NSEW]|^)(ST LOUIS){e<=1}`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: It should have the same effect... No, you removed the fuzzy matching part, which he needs.

Comment: @nhahtdh hmm..edited it..but i guess fuzzy matching would not be implemented on lookarounds..

Comment: Have you considered a simple two-pass approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a negative lookahead instead:

```
(?![NEW]|SS)(ST LOUIS){e<=1}
```

`(ST LOUIS){e<=1}` matches a string meeting the fuzzy conditions placed on it.
You want to prevent it from starting with `[NSEW]`. A negative lookahead does that for you `(?![NSEW])`. 
But your desired string starts with an `S` already, you only want to exclude the strings starting with an `S` added to the beginning of your string.
Such a string would start with `SS`, and that's why it's added to the negative lookahead.

Note that if you allow errors > 1, this probably wouldn't work as desired.

Comment: Ah yes, thought there was no `S` in there. Fixed for insertion.

Comment: Wow, that worked! You're suggestion makes no sense to me though. I'll check it off as an accepted answer, but could you (or someone else) explain the rationale for taking `S` out of the character class and placing it within an alternation instead (as a double `S`, no less)?

Comment: @user1185790, added a description.

Comment: Ah. That didn't even occur to me. Thanks so much for your help. This explains why the example I was going to give was working as expected - because there was no repeated letter between the character exception and the first letter of the matching string.