# Extract strings using fuzzy LR patterns in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, stringr

I am struggling for long time.

I manage to extract everything between my Right and Left patterns in a string as you can see in the following example.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data=c("everything will be ok one day")

str_extract(string = data, pattern = "(?<=thing).*(?=ok one)")
#> [1] " will be "
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As you notice in the code, I extract everything between "thing" and "ok one".

I need to incorporate the possibility of mismatches inside these patterns.
I want to allow a maximum of two **mismatches** and consider indels and insertions.

---

**Example1**

for example one mismatch that I want to account for
is the insertion of letter "s" in everything

```
dat.1=c("everythings will be ok one day")
```

I would like in this case to be able to extract the the phrase

```
will be
```

---

**Example 2**

```
dat.2=c("everythingswillbeokoneday")
```

I would like in this case to be able to extract the the phrase

```
will be
```

---

PS:
This is just a simplified example. My actual data does not contain gaps, and it's complicated. I am looking forward to receiving your help and guidance.

Comment: It's not perfectly clear. Please provide additional strings in your `data` that suggest the differences you're talking about. Once you've added that, it would help to show what you currently get and contrast that with the exact strings you *want* to get. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use fuzzy matching of strings, relying, for instance, on package `stringdist` and computing, for each delimiter string (`thing` and `ok`, in your example), the respective matching score (that is what the function `maxsim` does below).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringdist)

dat.1=c("everythings will be ok one day")

maxsim <- function(df, delim)
{
  df %>% 
    str_split(" ") %>% unlist %>% 
    map(~ stringsim(delim,.x)) %>% 
    which.max
} 

dat.1 %>% 
  str_split(" ") %>% unlist %>% 
  .[ (maxsim(dat.1,"thing") + 1) : (maxsim(dat.1,"ok") - 1) ] %>% 
  str_c(collapse = " ")

#> [1] "will be"
```

Comment: Paul this is a great answer and for this I upvoted it. 
My concern is that this works only with a space delimiter. How this would work if there were no gaps?

Comment: Thanks, @LDT. It would be best if you provided an example with no gaps.

Comment: You are right Paul! But overall I am so impressed because you had a genius idea

Comment: I have just added one example. Thank you again

Comment: Thanks, @LDT. I do not think we can do anything without adding some structure to the delimiters. More specifically, `thing` can be `things` and what else?

Comment: I like your splitting the words and then looking at the string distance—pure genius. I have seen this in python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691908/creating-fuzzy-matching-exceptions-with-pythons-new-regex-module. It is interesting because you indicate only how many errors you expect in your pattern. eg.,  with {e<=1} you indicate one error. 
The trivial thing is. How do you find in a string that is NOT separated by gaps a pattern that contains an error? 
Shall I ask better first this answer?

Comment: I believe that `stringdist` also allows us to specify the number of errors, @LDT. However, the crucial point is to _define_ clearly the problem -- that is what is missing at the moment. Take your example: `everythingswillbeokoneday` and the delimiters `thing` and `ok`. If we allow one error at most, we get `swillbe` or `willbe`. But how can we be sure which one of the two is the _valid_ string? In sum, it appears to me that your problem is not yet well defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241491/discussion-between-ldt-and-paul-smith).